# Event Receiver just works as administrator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm reading a parameter from the url in a site. Then i insert that data in a survey list, but that event receiver only works for administrator, when i use another user i cannot insert that data.
I already use elevate privileges. Can you help me with my problem.

Comment: could you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

How are you elevating your code?

Are you instatiating you site object elevated or are you using the context one ?

eg:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedprivileges(delegate()
{
     using(SPSite site = new SPSite(yoursiteid))
      {
         //site is elevated
      }
     SPSite site2 = SPContext.Current.Site;
     //site2 is not elevated
     //beacuse is a receiver you might be using 
     SPSite site3 = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
     //in this case site3 is also not elevated as you are reusing an existint instance
     //you could do this from the feature receiver (all this assuming that is a Site collection feautre) hence casting the Feature.Parent as SPSite
     using(SPSite site4 = new SPSite(site3.ID))
       {
        //site4 is and new instance and will be elevated
       }
});
```

Hope this helps